# Подстановка значений в DropDownList c#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

У меня есть DropDownList в asp.net, который берет лист значений из БД.
Я пытаюсь присвоить ему значения, которое есть в этом списке, но выходит так, что он добавляет в список просто еще одно точно такое же значение.[image: Так выглядит DDL]. Далее я пытаюсь подставить строчку и вот что происходит [image: подставил значение]. Поясните пожалуйста, как подставить строку в ddl.

```
//получение данных по складскому объекту/штабелю/карману
protected void txbBarcode_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string a = "";
    string b = "";
    int c = 0;
    //беру только 1 часть
    if (txbBarcode.Text != "")
    {
        var str = "УОГП-5.4.4";
        var splitted = str.Split('.');
        ddlZone.SelectedItem.Text = splitted[0];
    }
}
```

заполняю я свой ддл следующим образом.

```
 //заполнение выпадающего списка сотрудников
    try
    {
        ddlZone.Items.Clear();
        OleDbConnection conn = Master.Connect.ssssss();
        OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "select distinct ZONE_NAME from ssssss where ZONE_NAME is not null order by ZONE_NAME";
        OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            ddlZone.Items.Add(reader["ZONE_NAME"].ToString());
            ddlRelocationZone.Items.Add(reader["ZONE_NAME"].ToString());
        }
        reader.Close();
        reader.Dispose();
        cmd.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: `ddlZone.SelectedItem = splitted[0];`?

Comment: У `SelectedItem` нет сеттера. т.е. рид онли. либо `.Text` либо `.Value` нужно добавлять. Для числа это работает, а для строки нет

Comment: точнее так, если это число, то я использую `SelectedIndex` и это работает как надо

Comment: почему бы не юзать `SelectedIndex` и для выбора строки?

Comment: @tym32167 я не могу этого сделать, т.к. беру значение из строки, и он будет выбрасывать ошибку о неверном формате входной строки

Comment: ну там ещё есть `SelectedValue`, которое строка. И вы не показали, как вы зполняете ваш DropDown

Comment: @tym32167 используйте ваш комментарий как ответ, это решило мою проблему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте свойство [`SelectedValue`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue)

```
ddlZone.SelectedValue = splitted[0];
```